# Flutter chewie dispose not working when video fullscreen mode was used (landscape)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, video-player

Im using chewie package to play video in flutter, When i played the video and exit the page, dispose is working fine, but then when i use fullscreen and tried to exit the page the audio/video will still play. It says: dispose was called on null

Here is my code:

```
    class _ChewieListItemState extends State<ChewieListItem> {
      ChewieController _chewieController;


       @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Chewie(
            controller:_chewieController ,
          ),
        );
      }


      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        // Wrapper on top of the videoPlayerController
        _chewieController = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: widget.videoPlayerController,
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          // Prepare the video to be played and display the first frame
          autoInitialize: true,
          looping: widget.looping,
          autoPlay: false,
          allowFullScreen: true,
          allowedScreenSleep: false,
          // Errors can occur for example when trying to play a video
          // from a non-existent URL
          errorBuilder: (context, errorMessage) {
            return Center(
              child: Text(
                'Network Error, please try again',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }


    @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    widget.videoPlayerController.dispose();
    _chewieController.dispose();
  }

    }
```

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to use vimeo in flutter, because you find few things yet!

Comment: @karl 123 Did you find the solution,Facing same issue in my app

Answer (score 2):

***Initialize your videoPlayerController in the initState function aswell.***

```
class _ChewieListItemState extends State<ChewieListItem> {
  ChewieController _chewieController;
  VideoPlayerController videoPlayerController;




@override
void initState() {
     super.initState();
     videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.asset(path); // init controller here
    // Wrapper on top of the videoPlayerController
    _chewieController = ChewieController(
      videoPlayerController: videoPlayerController, // remove the widget tag
    );
  }


@override
void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    videoPlayerController.dispose(); // remove the widget tag here as well    
}

}
```

Just had the same problem and searched like 3 days for the solution.